# How to add API Gateway SDK to React?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, reactjs, reactive-programming, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to add API Gateway SDK to React code, but I'm new to ES6 and React so it's hard to find a way

This is my React project structure:

```
myReactProject
- node_modules
- src
-- components
---- ApigClient
------ lib (AWS APIGateway JS files) 
------ apigClient.js
------ ApigValidation.js
---- otherComponents..
---- index.js
-- containers
---- App
------ App.js
------ App.scss
---- Home
------ Home.js
------ Home.scss
---- OtherContainerFiles
---- index.js
-- redux
-- utils
---- validation.js
-- client.js
-- config.js
-- routes.js
-- server.js
```

And I was trying to import the API Gateway SDK in 2 ways:

1)

```
import ApigClient from './ApigClient';
import apiGatewayClient from './lib/apiGatewayCore/apiGatewayClient'
import sigV4ClientConfig from './lib/apiGatewayCore/sigV4ClientConfig'
import simpleHttpClientConfig from './lib/apiGatewayCore/simpleHttpClientConfig'
import utils from './lib/apiGatewayCore/utils'
import enc-base64 from './lib/CryptoJS/component/enc-base64'
import hmac from './lib/CryptoJS/component/hmac'
import hmac-sha256 from './lib/CryptoJS/rollups/hmac-sha256'
import sha256 from './lib/CryptoJS/rollups/sha256'
import axios from './lib/axios/dist/axios.standalone'
import url-template from './lib/url-template/url-template'
```

2)

```
class ApigValidation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/axios/dist/axios.standalone.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/CryptoJS/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/CryptoJS/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/CryptoJS/components/hmac.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/CryptoJS/components/enc-base64.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/url-template/url-template.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/apiGatewayCore/sigV4Client.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/apiGatewayCore/apiGatewayClient.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/apiGatewayCore/simpleHttpClient.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/apiGatewayCore/utils.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="apigClient.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          var apigClient = apigCleint.newClient({
            apiKey: 'This-is-my-api-key'
          });
          apigClient.myFuncGet(params, null)
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            }).catch(function(resuponse) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
        </script>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

1) Is the folder structure right? Should I put SDK in Utils?

2) How can I import/load/add JS SDK in react and enable get/post function?

Please advise, sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example as a base?

Comment: @markthethomas Yes! Exactly. Stating that would actually help readers to understand.. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! See my answer below for the options. With that starter it should be as easy as requiring it and configuring with an API key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React doesn't make any decisions about how you do your http/async data fetching or how you structure your project. So as far as a "correct" way, there are *many*. Look at [Redux](http://redux.js.org) for popular and well-known implementation/variation of the Flux.

In general, you can do one of two things to get an SDK or any sort of external code into your React app.

1. **Use a bundler**: Webpack, rollup.js, browserify, or other tools will output code in such a way that the SDK you need is accessible from the modules require it.
2. **include it in a script tag**: If you're running everything in the browser and don't want to bundle everything for whatever reason, you need to include the file in your HTML *before* React so you will get access to the global module(s) that get(s) exposed from whatever the SDK is.

For example:

```
<script src="copy_of_sdk_from_CDN"></script>
<script src="copy_of_react_from_CDN"></script>
<script src="other_app_code"></script>
<script src="other_app_code"></script>
```

You'd only need to do that *if* you're not using webpack or another bundler. Those bundlers should give you a file that contains everything in the right order as per the dependencies you've specified using `require` or `import` (if you're using ES6 modules)

These are pretty much the only ways to "get" the SDK into your project. You can pretty much either pull it in from a remote location or download it and use it that way (a la npm).

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks @markthethomas! However I didn't understand " include the file in your HTML before React".. Could you please explain it to me? Appreciated!!

Comment: Edited. Let me know if that still doesn't make sense. Do you have experience working with JavaScript and the browser? Might be confusing otherwise :) just curious

Comment: Oh sorry I was thinking too complicated. :/ Sometimes thinking simple is the best way you know.. Problem solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: Simple is hard, but simple is almost always best :)

Comment: How would you use bundler for this? Do you have some example?